# Get Checkbox Status in jQuery jTemplates

Tags: jquery, jtemplates

I have following jtemplate

```
{#foreach $T.d as post}
<input type='checkbox' >
{#/for}
```

Template render in DIV. I am not able to get checked checkbox in div

my code to find checked box below

```
$("#div").find(":checkbox:checked").length
```

It always returns `0`.

Comment: Are your checkboxes located within a `<div id="div" />`? Could you post the full template?

Comment: can you show us the generated html source

Answer (score 0):

seems to work ok for me if the checkbox is not checked you will get 0 here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/7dmsr/)

here is the js

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert($("#div").find(":checkbox:checked").length)
});
```

and html

```
<div id="div">
<input type='checkbox' >
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="test"/>
```

Comment: my checkbox not direct in div they render in div with the help of jtemplate

Comment: as long as they are loaded when you check them it shouldn't matter right